# For ICommand & DelegateCommand Which Thread Does it Run On?

Tags: wpf, multithreading

My application uses `ICommand`s to bind methods to Buttons.

I initialized these commands as follows :

```
AnswerCommand = new DelegateCommand(AnsCommandExecute, AnsCommandCanExecute);
```

I want to know if`AnsCommandExecute()` method will work on UI thread or Background thread?

If it works on UI thread do I have to create another thread for this execute() method as my application performs lot of processing in background.

Also my application uses TCP to communicate with one another application. so, for better performance Do I have to use different threads for Receiving Data, Processing, and Sending Data. 
what will be the best Threading approach for such applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way to find whether `AnsCommandExecute()` method works on main thread or not is to put break  point in the method and check call stack.

Quick answer is yes - `AnsCommandExecute()` will execute on main thread.

To answer your threading requirement, you can invoke content inside `AnsCommandExecute()` on separate thread. This will make UI responsive.

If you are going to receive responses asynchronously, you then have to move operation back to main thread with help of "[Dispatcher](https://web.archive.org/web/20080513013206/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)". More also at the [Dispatcher documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher).

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. MSDN says, 'Any work that doesn't need to be done on the UI thread should instead be moved off onto other threads for processing in the background'. Does this mean if my ObservableCollection is not bound/shown on UI then I can do all ObservableCollection related processing by creating new Thread?

Comment: Your ObservableCollection will be binding source (property of view model or model). So it will be part of main thread. You can move the TCP communication to other thread. Once data get retrieved from other thread, use Dispatcher to add the newly retrieved records in ObservableCollection.